# jQuery Validate - Checkbox Group ONLY ONE can be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, client-side-validation

I'm seeing a LOT of "at least one needs to be checked", but I'm not seeing any solutions on how to limit a checkbox group to only ONE can be checked.

***EDIT: 3/2/17 # 9:20am***

Why not a radio button?

Here's why:  This particular group of checkboxes lives inside a larger group of checkboxes that only require you to have at least one checked. I need to retain THAT rule, but also apply the rule, in this specific group, that only ONE of these can be selected - yet still maintain the overall group rule that at least one must be selected. Here's some markup:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="checkbox-group">
     <label><input type="checkbox" id="A" name="atLeastOne" value="A"> A</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" id="B" name="atLeastOne" value="B"> B</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" id="C" name="atLeastOne" value="C"> C</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" id="D" name="atLeastOne" value="D"> D</label>
          <div class="checkbox-group">
               <label><input type="checkbox" id="E" name="onlyOne" value="E"> E</label>
               <label><input type="checkbox" id="F" name="onlyOne" value="F"> F</label>
               <label><input type="checkbox" id="G" name="onlyOne" value="G"> G</label>
          </div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" id="H" name="atLeastOne" value="H"> H</label>
</div>
```

Hopefully this makes more sense than my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that only one option can be selected that rather use a **radio button** instead.

```
<input name="field" type="radio" />
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough, this solution still works. As long as the names are still the same, the jquery validator will still honor the require: at least one, and the radio button section will only allow one choice.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

```
<input type="radio">
```

Should fulfill your needs better than trying to validate checkboxes.